# How to dynamically load Li element's with other Javascript Array li

Tags: javascript, html, css, menu

I have a problem figuring out how to make my menu items dynamically change other list items when clicked on.

For example I want Box1:

```
<nav class="left">

                <ul>
                    <li>
                    <a href=""><br>box1</a>
                    </li>
...
```

to update the li's in the 'topnav' class:

```
<header class="topnav">

                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="">Item</a></li>
                            <li><a href="">Item2</a></li>
                            <li><a href="">Item3</a></li>
                        </ul>

                    </header>
```

so when a user clicks box1 menu item on the left class navigation menu, the for instance - 'Item'/'Item2'/'Item3' list item updates to lets say "NewItemName"/"NewItemName2"/"NewItemName3"

example codepen:
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/Epiom

edit:
 I am trying to change the li's of (item,item2,item3) with new ones when you click the side bars navigation buttons. ex, when you click settings the 3 top buttons(top nav li's) would change to profile settings, video settings, sound settings (these names are made up and not in the code)

Answer (score 0):

Check this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zen_coder/dacwa28L/2/) whose code is also below and tell me if it is what you want

```
<body>
    <header class="topnav">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="">Item</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="">Item2</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="">Item3</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </header>
    <nav class="left">
        <ul>
            <li>box</li>
            <li>otherbox</li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
    <script>
        $(function()
        {
            $(".left li").click(function()
            {
                var box = $(this).html();
                $( ".topnav li a" ).each(function( index ) 
                {
                    $(this).html("New" + box + "_" + index)
                });

            });
        });

    </script>
</body>
```

**EDIT:**

http://codepen.io/zen_coder/pen/beCKf

1. This code uses Jquery
2. Click on the right boxes and item menu will change
3. I had to remove the links href="" because unless the href starts with '#' and points inside the current page clicking the link makes you leave the page!

If you are just starting front end development you may want to have a look at:

1. http://www.w3schools.com/
2. http://jquery.com/
3. http://jqueryui.com/
4. http://getbootstrap.com/

Comment: it is almost what i was looking for, but i need it to not auto generate and use our pre defined variables.  Sorry i am just starting to get into javascript

Comment: @daveyedwards see my edit. Tell me if you need something else, or choose/validate the answer :D

Comment: sorry i was wondering how we make our own and not generated ones. We want to link to a array i think. We have a pre determined list that we want them all to change to when clicked

Comment: You need to edit your question and be precise. Tell exactly what you want, as I cannot guess what even you are not very sure could have. :)